# Using a WP shortcode in a Codeigniter view

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have a program built in codeigniter and am plugging it into a wordpress page.  I have managed to successfully hook in the header and footer.  It is running within the page as an iframe. With this I can hook in my plugin and I can grab wp functions with php and use them in my CI code.  So for example I am able to use something like:

$current_user->ID;
$current_user->user_firstname;

etc.

I can pass these wordpress to values in my CI View HTML.

What I would like to do now is to add an existing WP shortcode for paypal payment button into the html of my Codeigniter view. The nice thing about this short code is that it already is set up with a call back function to verify payment. Even though I am hooked in and can use the php functions, just placing the shortcode in the HTML does not do the trick. I figure this is because the body is not seen as a WP Page. How could I use an existing WP shortcode in my codeigniter application when hooked into WP?

If any are wondering how I am hooking in, this is the function I have created:

```
if (Config::WP_HEADER_FOOTER== TRUE) {
    if (substr(curPageURL(),0,-32)==$baseurl.'index.php/appointments/index/' || in_array(curPageURL(), array($baseurl,$baseurl.'?'))) {
    require('../wp-blog-header.php');

        add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 1);

        function ci_site_url() {

            include(FCPATH.'application/config/config.php');

            return $config['base_url'];
        }
        header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    }
}
```

And within the view I add this to the top of the HTML:

```
<?php
    if (Config::WP_HEADER_FOOTER== TRUE) {
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
?>
```

And at the footer I add:

```
<?php
    if (Config::WP_HEADER_FOOTER== TRUE) {
        get_footer();
    }   
?>
```

So if I turn on this function with in WP I get a lot of the WP features, I can use php functions, and template attributes are passed to my CI view, however I cannot yet use the shortcode. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Please do not ask me why I am using Codeigniter within WP and why I did not just write this within the WP structure.  I understand that they are different and it complicates things.  This is the structure I have to work in.  I am making it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]'); ?>
```

It works like a charm